# Remove focus on mat-button-toggle-group in Angular Material

Tags: css, angular-material

I have this code from Angular Material site and when I used this in Chrome I have focused on the button(like a blue border for each button selected).

```
<mat-button-toggle-group name="fontStyle" aria-label="Font Style">
  <mat-button-toggle value="bold">Bold</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="italic">Italic</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="underline">Underline</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

I tried to remove this with outline:none in Css, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I think the `outlines` should already be removed by angular material. If not you're on the right track.

You would need to add the following css:

```
.mat-button-toggle-button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Make sure to add this in your global `styles.css` and not in your scoped component styles. If this doesn't work, try to add an `!important` just in order to see if your styles get overwritten.

> Notice: Outlines provide visual feedback for links that have `focus` when navigating a web document using the TAB key (or equivalent). So they are really important for people with a visual impairment. If you remove them, always make sure to replace them with some other visual feedback on the focus state. Angular material does this by changing the background color.

Comment: Thanks, it works but however I still have a border(not the blue one).

Comment: @NoName What about `border: none;`?